# how configure two instances with nginx and terraform?

Tags: docker, nginx, cloud, odoo, terraform

I have this code:

```
resource "docker_image" "nginx" {                        
  name = "nginx:1.11-alpine"                             
}                                                        
resource "docker_container" "nginx-server" {          
  name = "nginx-server"                               
  image = "${docker_image.nginx.latest}"              
  ports {                                             
    internal = 80                                     
    external = 80                                     
  }                                                   
  volumes {                                           
    container_path  = "/usr/share/nginx/html"         
    host_path = "/home/scrapbook/tutorial/www"        
    read_only = true                                  
  }                                                   
}
```

in a terraform file (.tf) ... I want to configure two instances of a web program that are served in two different ports on the same server.

```
resource "docker_container" "Odoo-iku_1" {                 
  name  = "Odoo-iku 1"                                     
  image = "ikusolutions/odoo-iku:latest"                 
  links = ["db"]                                         
  ports {                                                
    external = 8070                                      
    internal = 8069                                   
  }    
}
```

and

```
resource "docker_container" "Odoo-iku_2" {                 
  name  = "Odoo-iku 2"                                     
  image = "ikusolutions/odoo-iku:latest"                 
  links = ["db"]                                         
  ports {                                                
    external = 8071                                      
    internal = 8069                                   
  }    
}
```

**How do I make nginx address the external ports 8070 and 8071 to domain names?** example: port 8070 is directed to https://iku.solutions and port 8071 is directed to https://demo.iku.solutions

Answer (score 1):

Nginx routes the traffic hitting the server according to the way you configure it.
In your case, you want to configure nginx as a reverse proxy that routes the requests according to the server name they're trying to reach. This configuration should work for you, assuming requests for Odoo-iku 1 Odoo-iku 2 are coming from Odoo-iku1.example.com and Odoo-iku2.example.com, respectively -

```
server {
  listen      8001 default_server;
  server_name Odoo-iku1.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8071;
  }
}

server {
  listen      8002 default_server;
  server_name Odoo-iku2.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8070;
  }
}

upstream main {
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
  server 127.0.0.1:8002;
}

server {
  listen      80;
  server_name example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://main;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can this configuration apply for a terraform infrastructure? I could not make it work.

Comment: The example I gave is the nginx configuration your nginx configuration should contain, You can add the configuration I wrote in the answer to the `nginx.conf` file nginx currently uses, and then load it into the container by adding it as volume in terraform

Comment: `resource "docker_container" "nginx-server" {          
      name = "nginx-server"                                 
      image = "nginx:latest"                                 
      ports {                                                
        internal = 80                            
      }                                          
      volumes {                             
        container_path  = "./nginx.conf"        
        read_only = true                        
      }                                         
    }`

Comment: how to set nginx.conf and volumes?